# ML06 Micro To Micro USB wiring

Tags: wiring, dac

I tried to DIY to make a custom cable like the one in link:

https://www.fiio.co.in/collections/accessories/products/ml06-micro-to-micro-usb-data-cable?variant=12395665326185

I bought 2 normal usb to micro cables, cut them and soldered by matching colors but it does not work.  I also tried swapping white and green.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

That cable:

[image]

Isn't just a simple (micro)USB to (micro)USB connection, there is more going on.

Normally a (micro)USB connector (for example on a phone) is configured as a **peripheral** meaning that is expects to be connected to a USB **host** which is usually a PC.

Some peripherals like a phone support [USB On-The-Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) which means that they can be changed from behaving as a peripheral into a host. This for example allows to use USB flash drive to be connected directly to the phone and be available for storage.

To indicate to the phone that it needs to go into USB OTG mode, there is an extra connection (pin) present in the micro-USB plug.

[image]

Note the yellow Sense/ID line. This pin is almost always **unconnected** in a standard micro-USB cable. Also there is usually **no wire connected to it**. So I would be surprised if you can even convert a standard micro-USB to a micro-USB-OTG connector. The connection isn't there and it is not accessible. Standard micro USB cables don't need this connection so it isn't included.

Conclusion: just **buy** that cable or any other USB-OTG cable. It is simply not worth it to try and make your own.